# Select rows from comma collected ids in a column

Tags: mysql, sql, rel

My db is:

```
# item_rel
id | item_ids
--------------------------
1  | 1,2,4,6,8,10
2  | 3,5,7
3  | 9,11,12
.. | ............

# items
id | name
--------------------------
1  | Lorem
2  | Ipsum
3  | Sed
4  | Amed
.. | ............
```

The problem is select items with one query. I have tried many way but no luck. Only this one approachs the expected result:

```
SELECT
    items.*
FROM
    items
WHERE
    items.id IN (
        SELECT
            items_rel.ids
        FROM
            items_rel
        WHERE
            items_rel.ids LIKE "1" OR
            items_rel.ids LIKE "1,%" OR
            items_rel.ids LIKE "%,1" OR
            items_rel.ids LIKE "%,1,%"
    )
```

This query returns only one item.. How to get every item with one query?

Comment: Fix your data structure!  Learn what a junction table is!

Comment: Your expected output is not obvious. Only rows with the number 1 or any row that has a number that contains the digit 1, or...? Or do you want to extract all id values from the row containing id 1 and then join all of them?

Comment: Also make sure your query matches your table definitions for clarity.

Comment: Learn some database design.  "I have tried many way but no luck", if you had designed your database properly, you may have had much move luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bit tricky, but was so not imposible, nor a sign of ignorance:

```
SET @ids = (SELECT ids FROM item_rel
    WHERE ids LIKE '1' OR ids LIKE '1,%' OR ids LIKE '%,1' OR ids LIKE '%,1,%') ;
SET @ids = (SELECT IF (@ids IS NOT NULL,@ids,'99999999999999999999999')) ;
SET @q = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM items WHERE ID IN (', @ids,')') ;
PREPARE stmt FROM @q ;
EXECUTE stmt ;
```

"99999999999999999999999" must be any value that never found in your db.

Answer (score 3):

There are many, many reasons not to store ids in comma-delimited lists:

- Values should be stored using the appropriate type.  Numbers should not be stored as strings.
- Foreign keys should be properly declared.  You cannot declare foreign key relationships.
- SQL tables traditionally have one value per column, not a variable number.
- SQL has pretty poor string processing capabilities.
- Queries on such structures cannot readily make use of indexes.
- SQL has a really great data structure for storing lists.  It is called a `table`.

Sometimes, we are stuck with other people's really, really, really, really, really, really bad decisions.

MySQL offset a work-around called `find_in_set()`:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM items i JOIN
     items_rel ir
     ON find_in_set(i.id, ir.ids) > 0;
```

However, you should put your effort into fixing the data model, not getting the query to work.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity) is one place to start.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as said above please redesign the tables.
But if you cannot, the way to make this work is to add some more Commas in the query--
that is to add a leading and trailing comma to satisfy the    Where...LIKE...

```
SELECT
    Rows_items.*
FROM
    Rows_items
WHERE
    Rows_items.id IN (
        SELECT
            Rows_item_rel.id
        FROM
            Rows_item_rel
        WHERE
            ',' + Rows_item_rel.item_ids + ','  LIKE '%,' + '1' + ',%' 

    )
```